# updating glibc from rpm, YUM not access

Tags: redhat, rpm, glibc

Because of GHOST: glibc vulnerability, I need to upgrade glibc but server don't have yum access because not open firewall for it.

Current glibc:


glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

nscd-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

**upgrade glibc:**

glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm

glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686.rpm

glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm

glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm

nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh *rpm

but I encountered some kind of dependency error


[root]# rpm -Uvh *.rpm

warning: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY

error: Failed dependencies:

libBrokenLocale.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libanl.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libcidn.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libcrypt.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libdl.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libm.so.6 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libnsl.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libnss_compat.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libnss_dns.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libnss_files.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libnss_hesiod.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libnss_nis.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libnss_nisplus.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libresolv.so.2 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

librt.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libthread_db.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

libutil.so.1 is needed by glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

glibc = 2.12-1.149.el6 is needed by (installed) glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6 is needed by (installed) glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

when i try yum local, looks similar issue.

[root]# yum localinstall *.rpm

Loaded plugins: downloadonly, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager

There was an error communicating with RHN.

RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.

Error communicating with server. The message was:

Proxy Authentication Required

Setting up Local Package Process

Examining glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64

Marking glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

Examining glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64

Marking glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

Examining glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686.rpm: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686

Marking glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.i686.rpm as an update to glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

Examining glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm: glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64

Marking glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

Examining nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm: nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64
Marking nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm as an update to nscd-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

Resolving Dependencies

--> Running transaction check

---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6 will be updated

--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.12-1.149.el6 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.7 will be an update

---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6 will be updated

---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.7 will be an update

---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6 will be updated

--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64

---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.7 will be an update

---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6 will be updated
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           Requires: glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6
           Removing: glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6
           Updated By: glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64 (/glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64)
               glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6_6.7
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           Requires: glibc = 2.12-1.149.el6
           Removing: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               glibc = 2.12-1.149.el6
           Updated By: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64 (/glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64)
               glibc = 2.12-1.149.el6_6.7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: if skip dependency check, is it ok? e.g.
rpm -Uvh --nodeps glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 1):

You have glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.**i686**.rpm

You probably want to download and install glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.**x86_64**.rpm instead, since all the other packages are also X86_64

Comment: opps. it works after using x86_64 one. Thanks a lot.